# Complex analysis understanding

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

I do not understand the concept. Please, help me out.

Let $z = e^{i\theta} \in S^1$ , $S^1 = \{z:|z|=1\}$.
Suppose that $z$ is a root of $1$, i.e, $z=e^{2\pi i p/q}$ , $p, q \in \mathbb Z, q>0$.
For $n\geq q,\ q \mid n!$ and $z^{n!}=1$.

So,
$$\sum_{n =1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}z^n +\sum_{n =q}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

**My question**
How can we break it into two parts with different summands like that?

Comment: Are you sure the first summand is $\sum_{n=1}^{q-1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} z^n$ and not $\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n!}$?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your question. As you write, we have $z^{n!} = 1$ for $n \ge q$, this gives 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-1} z^{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{q-1} (-1)^n   n^{-1} z^{n\color{red}!} + \sum_{n=q}^\infty  (-1)^n n^{-1} $$
where is the last term, the $z^{n!}$ is left off, as it is equal to 1.

Comment: How to attach a file?

Comment: @user73195 You can only upload images.

Comment: Put it somewhere and give a link.

Comment: Thanks all. I think it may be a typo for n! like what  martini said. But the second sum is correct and Daniel Littlewood explained it well on his answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you made a typo. The sum can be split as follows, obviously $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}z^{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}z^{n!}+\sum_{n=q}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}z^{n!}$$
But note that you've already said $z^{q}=1$, so for $n\ge q$, $z^{n!}=(z^{q})^{N}=1^{N}=1$ for some number $N$. So the sum becomes 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}z^{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{q-1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}z^{n!}+\sum_{n=q}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$$